# In linked-list, how does the compiler understand that it needs to append nodes to the linked list class?

Tags: python, class, linked-list

I was trying to understand how linked-list works. I wrote a python code to create a linked-list and access its nodes.
I have used a class named 'Node' to create a 'Node' object, whereas, the class 'SLinkedList' would create an object in which I will store all nodes.
Here is the python code:

```
#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
# CREATING A LINKED LIST#####################
# Node creation
class Node:
    def __init__(self, dataval=None):
        self.dataval = dataval # assigning dataval 
        self.nextval = None  # for new node, nextvalue is Null
# Linked list creation
class SLinkedList:
    def __init__(self):  # empty linked list
        self.headval = None
    def listprint(self):   # for printing linked list
        printval = self.headval
        while printval is not None: # None is null object
            print (printval.dataval) # printing the head value
            printval = printval.nextval # jumping to next value

list1 = SLinkedList() # new linked list

e1 = Node(2)
e2 = Node(4)
e3 = Node(3)
list1.headval =e1
# Link first Node to second node
list1.headval.nextval = e2
# Link second Node to third node
e2.nextval = e3

e1 = Node(5)
e2 = Node(6)
e3 = Node(4)

list2 = SLinkedList()  # new linked list
list2.headval=e1
list2.headval.nextval=e2
e2.nextval=e3

#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
# Accessing a linked list~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

print('List 1')
list1.listprint()

print ('\nList 2')
list2.listprint()
```

I just wanted to know how `e2.nextval = e3` can append an item in the linked-list `SLinkedList()`? I can't see anything feature related to `nextval` that can append the node in the linked-list `SLinkedList()`.

Comment: Draw it out on paper.  Draw your nodes, draw arrows between them.  The KEY is that a linked list is not just "one thing".  There is no central list.  Each node only knows the location of the next node in line.  As long as you know the start, you can find any node in the list by hopping the links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may help to draw what is happening:

`list1 = SLinkedList() # new linked list`

This creates a linked list instance, which has no nodes yet:

```
list1
 ↓
┌────────────────┐ 
│ headval: None  │
└────────────────┘
```

`e1 = Node(2)`, `e2 = Node(4)` and `e3 = Node(3)` create three node instances. So now we have:

```
list1               e1                  e2                 e3
 ↓                   ↓                   ↓                  ↓
┌────────────────┐ ┌────────────────┐ ┌────────────────┐ ┌────────────────┐ 
│                │ │ dataval: 2     │ │ dataval: 4     │ │ dataval: 3     │
│ headval: None  │ │ nextval: None  │ │ nextval: None  │ │ nextval: None  │
└────────────────┘ └────────────────┘ └────────────────┘ └────────────────┘
```

All these entities are independent from each other. But then the code proceeds to establish links:

`list1.headval =e1`

```
list1               e1                  e2                 e3
 ↓                   ↓                   ↓                  ↓
┌────────────────┐ ┌────────────────┐ ┌────────────────┐ ┌────────────────┐ 
│                │ │ dataval: 2     │ │ dataval: 4     │ │ dataval: 3     │
│ headval: →→→→→→→→│ nextval: None  │ │ nextval: None  │ │ nextval: None  │
└────────────────┘ └────────────────┘ └────────────────┘ └────────────────┘
```

Note how `list1.headval` references the same thing as `e1`.

`list1.headval.nextval = e2`

This is a long way of putting it, because the previous assignment made `list1.headval` equal to `e1`, and so we could write here `e1.nextval = e2` instead -- it would do exactly the same thing:

```
list1               e1                  e2                 e3
 ↓                   ↓                   ↓                  ↓
┌────────────────┐ ┌────────────────┐ ┌────────────────┐ ┌────────────────┐ 
│                │ │ dataval: 2     │ │ dataval: 4     │ │ dataval: 3     │
│ headval: →→→→→→→→│ nextval: →→→→→→→→│ nextval: None  │ │ nextval: None  │
└────────────────┘ └────────────────┘ └────────────────┘ └────────────────┘
```

Note how `list1.headval.nextval` references the same thing as `e1.nextval`, and as `e2`.

`e2.nextval = e3`

Here the short way of putting it was used. We get this situation:

```
list1               e1                  e2                 e3
 ↓                   ↓                   ↓                  ↓
┌────────────────┐ ┌────────────────┐ ┌────────────────┐ ┌────────────────┐ 
│                │ │ dataval: 2     │ │ dataval: 4     │ │ dataval: 3     │
│ headval: →→→→→→→→│ nextval: →→→→→→→→│ nextval: →→→→→→→→│ nextval: None  │
└────────────────┘ └────────────────┘ └────────────────┘ └────────────────┘
```

And at this point all nodes are reachable starting from `list1`. We still have direct references to each node (`e1`, `e2`, `e3`), but at this point you could forget about those and walk from one node to the next via the `headval` and `nextval` properties.